# Anonymously upload to my Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I work remotely on camera systems and sometimes I have to backup some footage to cloud storage. Up to this point I've been signing into my Google Drive and uploading the files there for me to download at the home location.

However, the uploads usually take a while and I'd rather not leave the remote computer logged in and unattended while they are uploading. Is there any way I can upload to my drive without signing in (perhaps doing a one-time code or something of the sort)?

Comment: Why not just lock the computer?

Comment: The computer doesn't have a password (which is a requirement of the camera software). Regardless that would require me constantly having to unlock it to check the progress.

Comment: So you'd like to have the remote computer not logged and still be uploading photos to gdrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

[Allow Others to Upload Files to Your Google Drive with This Script](http://lifehacker.com/allow-others-to-upload-files-to-your-google-drive-with-1567528648)

The script itself is [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/):

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Once added to drive people can submit using a form:

```
<form id="myForm">

    <label>Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName">

    <label>Pick a file</label>
    <input type="file" name="myFile">

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
               onclick="google.script.run
                        .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                        return false;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [goFileDrop](http://gofiledrop.blogspot.in/2013/12/quick-start-how-to-receive-files-with.html) to send files to your google drive. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Anonymous upload is possible. May be third party plugin allow it. But it's risky. The best option is to create a secondary/temporary Google account. Create a folder on it and [transfer ownership](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892) to the primary account. Upload files to that folder. When you transfer ownership of a folder from yourself to another person, the new owner of the folder becomes an editor of the files in that folder. The original owners of the files remain the owners. From time to time you can move the files from the shared folder from the primary account. The secondary account has only limited privilege on the folder.